# Hibernate throw "org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection" Randomly in a Multi-Thread application

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, heroku

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static SessionFactory INSTANCE_SESSION_FACTORY = null;

public enum Common {
    SUCCESS, ROLLBACK
}

private synchronized static void createSessionFactory() {
    try {
        if (INSTANCE_SESSION_FACTORY != null) {
            return;
        }
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application");
        Integer environment = Integer.valueOf(rb.getString("environment"));

        Properties prop = new Properties();

        switch (environment) {
        /* LOCAL */
        case 1:
            prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", rb.getString("hibernate.driver.class.name"));
            prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", rb.getString("hibernate.db.uri"));
            prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", rb.getString("hibernate.db.username"));
            prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", rb.getString("hibernate.db.password"));
            break;
        default:
            throw new ConfigurationException(environment == null ? "No environment added in application.properties"
                    : "Wrong environment added in application.properties");
        }

        prop.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.pool_size", "100");

        prop.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize", "5");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize", "100");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.initialPoolSize", "10");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "1800");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=", "50");

        org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration config = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration().addProperties(prop)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Account.class).addAnnotatedClass(InsynctiveProperty.class)
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties())
        .buildServiceRegistry();
        INSTANCE_SESSION_FACTORY = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if (INSTANCE_SESSION_FACTORY == null) {
        createSessionFactory();
    }
    return INSTANCE_SESSION_FACTORY;
}

public static Session getCurrentSession() {
    return getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
}

public static Session openSession() {
    return getSessionFactory().openSession();
}

public static void closeCurrentSession() {
    getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().close();
}

public synchronized static Object get(Class<?> clazz, Integer id) {
    Session session = getCurrentSession();
    final Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        Object obj = session.get(clazz, id);
        transaction.commit();
        return obj;
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        transaction.rollback();
        throw ex;
    } finally {

    }
}

public Common save(Object object) {
    Session session = openCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    Common result = null;
    try {
        transaction = openTransaction(session);
        session.save(object);
        transaction.commit();
        result = Common.SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (transaction != null) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        result = Common.ROLLBACK;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return result;
}

public Common update(Object object) {
    Session session = openCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    Common result;

    try {
        transaction = openTransaction(session);
        session.update(object);
        transaction.commit();
        result = Common.SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        if (transaction != null) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        result = Common.ROLLBACK;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return result;
}

public Session openCurrentSession() {
    return getSessionFactory().openSession();
}

public Transaction openTransaction(Session session) {
    return session.beginTransaction();
}
}
```

Sometimes when a use one of these mehtods I recive this error:

> org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
>
> [org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131),
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49),
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125),
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110),
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304),
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169),
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67),
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160),
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1396),
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method),
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62),
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43),
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483),
>   org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352),
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy66.beginTransaction(Unknown Source),
>   insynctive.utils.HibernateUtil.get(HibernateUtil.java:123),
>   insynctive.tests.TestMachine.tearUp(TestMachine.java:104),
>   insynctive.tests.PersonFileTest.tearUp(PersonFileTest.java:52),
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method),
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62),
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43),
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483),
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85),
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:517),
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213),
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:140),
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:170),
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:104),
>   org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:771),
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621),
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357),
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352),
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310),
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259),
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52),
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86),
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1199),
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1124),
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1032),
>   insynctive.runnable.RunnableTest.run(RunnableTest.java:15),
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)]

**SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131**

```
else if ( CONNECTION_CATEGORIES.contains( sqlStateClassCode ) ) {
                    return new JDBCConnectionException( message, sqlException, sql );
```

And I need to restart the pool sessions to continue working..

*Any idea whats happens?*
My application is a **Multi Thread application**, I throw like **6-10 threads**.

***Note***
I'm using a Heroku DB (ClearDB MySQL) when I used a local DB i cant reproduce this error.

Comment: please provide the entire stack trace.

Comment: maybe you are running into a connectivity problem on heroku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have implemented the double checked locking pattern.  in order for it to work correctly, you must make the `INSTANCE_SESSION_FACTORY` variable `volatile`.

note, that may or may not be the cause of the exception, but it is certainly a bug in your code.

UPDATE:

It's possible you are simply running into scenarios where your pooled connections have timed out.  you might want to try enabling c3p0's idle connection checking (something like "idleConnectionTestPeriod=300").

Comment: Thanks, Any idea on my bug? I don't know why sometimes hibernate can not open the connection.. and sometimes yes.

Comment: @EugenioValeiras - did you see my comment above?

Comment: Yes! I added the full stacktrace.

Comment: @EugenioValeiras - sorry, no idea.  that exception doesn't look like the "real" exception (a conversion of some other underlying error).  probably need to determine the true underlying error before you will be able to figure out how to solve it.